# 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token - can't sign in with Twitter

Tags: python, django, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to add twitter sign in option to my python application and I'm getting following error from web server:

GET /social-auth/login/twitter/ HTTP/1.1" 500 103190 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token

I work on dev environment django + unicorn with SSL on localhost. I've checked following instruction on Twitter callback url's guide:

Don’t use localhost as a callback URL Instead of using localhost, please use a custom host locally or http(s)://127.0.0.1.

My callback URL: https://127.0.0.1:8000/social-auth/complete/twitter/

Is it possible to make it work without hosting real domain?

Comment: They literally said use don't use localhost, even use http://127.0.0.1:8000 and that would be sufficient. If you have a code or something then provide it.

Comment: please provide code

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can test your API on the development server.

Try this one:

```
https://localhost:8000/complete/twitter/
                 or 
https://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/twitter/
```

Update your callback URL in your [App's Setting](http://%20https://apps.twitter.com/).

Refer to this article for more understanding :

> https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/issues/164